# Firebase deploy of Cloud Functions fail with TypeScript

Tags: firebase, ionic3, firebase-hosting

I want to host my Ionic app to firebase hosting. Now when I run `firebase deploy` command I got below error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tslint -p tslint.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Error: functions predeploy command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

What I am missing to work this properly

Comment: Are you trying to deploy just hosting?  What about functions?  It looks like you have TypeScript configured.

Comment: I first received function error and i fix that error. I want to deploy my ionic app

Comment: maybe this helps you out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3SngzhT95Q

Answer (score 2):

Change in Package.json

```
"build": "node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc"
```

to

```
"build": "node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json && tsc"
```

this will work for you.

Comment: there is no "build" key in Package.json

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is going to the functions folder and 'npm i typescript', which updated it to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `functions` folder a cause can be an error in some `.ts` file (`index.ts` or other file that you manually created), but it doesn't show on log